# How to configure RubyMine to preserve Ruby 1.9.2 hash syntax when transforming code?

Tags: ruby, rubymine

RubyMine can toggle block syntax between `do;end` and `{ }` block notation. For example, given the following code:

```
[1, 2, 3].each do |i|
  puts i
end
```

I can place the caret at `do` and press Option-Enter Enter (on the Mac) to convert this code snippet to:

```
[1, 2, 3].each { |i| puts i }
```

Doing the same with the caret at the `{` performs the reverse transformation.

However when the code inside the block contains Ruby 1.9.2's new hash syntax, RubyMine destroys it during the transformation:

```
# before
[1, 2, 3].each { |i| some_func(param: i) }

# after
[1, 2, 3].each do |i|
  some_func(param : i)
end
```

Note the space between `param` and the `:`.

I looked through the Ruby style options in RubyMine's preferences but wasn't able to find anything which controls colons. How can I prevent RubyMine from messing around with my colons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be a bug, I've submitted it to the RubyMine issue tracker, feel free to [watch/vote](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RUBY-9690).

Comment: Great, thanks. I was sure I was just missing some configuration option somewhere.